# How do you abort a Bacon.js Property that is making an AJAX request once 404 is reached?

Tags: javascript, bacon.js

I have some `Property` that is making AJAX requests on fire. However, once case `404` is reached, I'd like to terminate this stream, but I'm not sure how to do so. Below is the code:

```
// load :: EventStream (Int -> Int)
load = $("#loadimg")
    .asEventStream("click")
    .map(function(e){ return function(x){ return x + 1 }})

// loadP :: Property Int
loadP = load.scan(1, function(x,f){ return f(x) })

// loadImg :: Property (HttpRequest -> Either String String)
loadImg = loadP
    .flatMapLatest(function(i){ return Bacon.fromPromise(imgLoader(i) )})
    .mapError("")

// imgLoader :: Int -> HttpRequest String
imgLoader = function(id){

    // pretend src, root and fmt are global variables
    var url = src + root + id + fmt

    return $.ajax({ 
        type   : "GET",
        url    : url,
    })
    .then(function(ys){ return url })

}

// EventStreamT (State Dom) String
loadImg.onValue(function(url){

    if (url.length == 0) return url        
    else return appendImg("#imgs", "name", url);

})
```

It doesn't make sense to me to put this "abort bacon property" code in the very last function, where the side-effect is located, but where else would I test for `404` case? And how would I terminate the thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bacon.js 0.6.17, you can pass a predicate function to `endOnError`, so you can do

loadImg = loadP
    .flatMapLatest(function(i){ return Bacon.fromPromise(imgLoader(i) )})
    .endOnError(function(error) { return error.status == 404 })

Answer (score 1):

You could simply say `.endOnError()` instead of `.mapError("")` to end on any error.

If you need more specific handling per error type, you can do

```
loadImg404 = loadImg.mapError(".status").filter(function(status) { return status==404 })
...
loadImg.takeUntil(loadImg404).onValue(..)
```